# Why IPython %autoreload reinitialize my variables?

Tags: python, ipython

I have this module:

```
foo = []
```

And from IPython I do:

```
In [1]: foo.append(42)
In [2]: foo
Out [2]: [42]
```

Then I edit my module that forces IPython to reload my module

```
In [3]: foo
Out [3]: []
```

In my module I need to keep the handlers of returned by some DLL functions. They have to be kept during all the session, but when I debug my module and it is automatically reloaded, I lost these handlers.

How to prevent IPython from resetting the variables?

Comment: The variable is initialized in the module, so reloading the module reinitializes the variable. It can't be any other way.

Comment: Is there any possible workaround? Using another module just for storing these values?

Comment: You could try that. Or (horrible hack) store the values in the `__builtin__` module.